# I am trying to create a search function from an Input field to search through multiple tables relationally linked together

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to implement a search through multiple tables. The project is an online store with 3 distinctive tables, Products, Categories and Brands. I can only search through the Products table but can't seem to get the same search field from my blade file to search either the categories or the brands and return results of the associated products.
My Blade search input

```
<form action="{{ url('/search-products') }}" method="post">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row" style="display: flex;">
      <input class="typeahead form-control form-control-lg" type="text" name="product" id="product" placeholder="Search item to buy here..." style="width: 220px;"> &nbsp
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="ti-search"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

My search function in my controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Image;
use App\Category;
use App\Brands;
use App\Product;
use DB;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
   public function searchProducts(Request $request) {
        $product = $request->input('product');

        $categories = Category::with('categories')->where(['parent_id' => 0])->get();

        $productsAll = Product::query()->where('product_name', 'LIKE', "%{$product}%")
        ->orWhere('state', 'LIKE', "%{$product}%")
        ->orWhere('lga', 'LIKE', "%{$product}%")
        ->orWhere('category_id', 'LIKE', "%{$product}%")->where('status', 1)->get();

        $breadcrumb = "<a href='/'>Home</a> / ".$product;

        return view('pages.results')->with(compact('categories', 'productsAll',  'product', 'breadcrumb'));
    }
}
```

My Products Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;
use Session;
use DB;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['category'];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'id');
    }
}
```

My Category Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product','id');
    }
}
```

My Brands Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Brands extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find `Categories` that have `Products` like the given `searchTerm`, you could do the following:

**SearchController.php**

```php
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $Request)
    {
        $searchTerm = $request->product;

        $categories = Categories::whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($searchTerm){
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
        })
        ->with(['products' => function($query) use ($searchTerm){
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
        }])->get();

        return view('search-results-view', compact('categories));
    }
}
```

You'll then have a `collection` of `Categories` with the `Products` eager loaded.

Having passed the `$categories` to the returned view (above), you'll be able to loop over the `Categories` and the related `Products` in your blade file.

**search-results-view.blade.php**

```php
@foreach ($categories as $category)
  <h4>{{ $category->name }}</h4>

  @foreach ($category->products as $product)
    {{ $product->name }}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

You can use the same principal to work on your `Brands` model.

Comment: Will the collection of categories ith products eager loaded be in the Categories model or in the blade file?

Comment: The `$categories` would be passed to your blade file. I have updated my answer to give you an example.

Comment: I have tried it, it is returning an error on typing a category name `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`id` in (11) and `name` like %Vehicle%)` while returning nothing on typing an actual product

Comment: You will need to replace the field in the `where` clause with the name of a field in your table.

Comment: Replaced the clause as suggested and its not returning any error when actual products is typed but nothing is returned at both instances. `$cat = Category::whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($searchTerm){
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
        })
        ->with(['products' => function($query) use ($searchTerm){
            $query->where('product_name', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
        }])->get();`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by using the join function of eloquent to query multiple tables. I edited my search function in my controller as follows

```
public function searchProducts(Request $request) {
        $product = $request->input('product');

        $categories = Category::with('categories')->where(['parent_id' => 0])->get();

        $productsAll = Category::query()->join('products', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                                    ->where('categories.name', 'LIKE', "%{$product}%")
                                    ->orWhere('products.product_name', 'LIKE', "%{$product}%")
                                    ->where('products.status', 1)->get();


        $breadcrumb = "<a href='/'>Home</a> / ".$product;

        return view('pages.results')->with(compact('categories','productsAll','product','breadcrumb'));

    }
```

And My Category Controller

```
class Category extends Model implements Searchable
{
    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];
    public function categories(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category','id');
    }

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product','id');
    }
}
```

And My Product Controller

```
class Category extends Model implements Searchable
{
    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];
    public function categories(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category','id');
    }

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product','id');
    }
}
```